# Java 8: DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

Basically, I am trying to parse a string to a timestamp.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Timestamp:" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS").parse("20180301050630663"));
}
```

I got an exception saying that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20180301050630663' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Lob.main(Lob.java:41)
```

Then I tried doing this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse("20180301050630663", fmt);
System.out.println("Timestamp:" + timestamp);
```

And got the same exception error too.

What have I done wrong here? Ideally, I want to store the timestamp to a variable and compare it with another timestamp that I am reading in . How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A bug of JDK8 and has been resolved in JDK9:

https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8031085

Update

As User @Aaron said in comment, you can use the workaround that is included in the bug tracker IMO:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3).toFormatter();
    System.out.println("Timestamp:" + dtf.parse("20180301050630663"));
}
```

Comment: As a workaround, if applicable, adding any separator works: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS").parse("2018-03-01-05-06-30-663")`

Comment: @HBo That's right.

Comment: Better use the workaround that is included in the bug tracker IMO : `DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3).toFormatter()`

Comment: @Aaron dude, you killed my vibe... But you're totally right about it!

Comment: @HBo sorry about your vibe, may it rest in peace ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a bug. That code works in Java 10 (and 9, it seems).

You can go around the issue using java.text.SimpleDateFormat:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS').
                 parse("20180301050630663")
```

Which works just fine (`Thu Mar 01 05:06:30 SAST 2018` is the output in my TZ):

Comment: Works in Java 9 too. Timestamp:{},ISO resolved to 2018-03-01T05:06:30.663